# php Regular expression fails

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to match string but it is going into last else loop. Can you please provide any help?

```
$cstg = "<result>True<\/result>";

if (preg_match("/<result>True<\/result>/", $cstg)) {
    echo "result success";
}
else if (preg_match("/\<result\>False\<\/result\>/", $cstg)) {
    echo "result fail";
}
else {
    echo "Something went wrong.";
}
```

Comment: Also (not trying to be pedantic or anything), but they're called "*branches*" not "loops". The entire `if`/`elseif`/`else` block is called a "*conditional*" and the code between each `{` and `}` is called a "*branch*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is coming from your `$cstg` string. You don't have to escape \ in html text. So following code are working fine:

```
$cstg = "<result>True</result>";

if( preg_match("/<result>True<\/result>/", $cstg)){
    echo "result success";
}
elseif  (preg_match("/\<result\>False\<\/result\>/", $cstg)){
    echo "result fail";
}else{
    echo "Something went wrong.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$cstg ="<result>True</result>";
$find="<result>False<\/result>";

if( preg_match("/$find/", $cstg)){
    echo "result success";
}
elseif  (preg_match("/$find/", $cstg)){
    echo "result fail";
}else{
    echo "Something went wrong.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape the `'/'` when defining `$cstg`. When I remove the escape from `$cstg`, your example runs correctly. Another thing to point out, is that you don't need to escape `<` and `>` in your `prce_match()`. This code works for me:

```
<?php
$cstg = "<result>True</result>";

if (preg_match("/<result>True<\/result>/", $cstg))
{
    echo "result success";
}
elseif  (preg_match("/<result>False<\/result>/", $cstg))
{
    echo "result fail";
}
else
{
    echo "Something went wrong.";
}
```

You can see that you're putting a literal `'\'` into `$cstg` as follows:

```
<?php
$cstg = "<result>True<\/result>";
echo $cstg;
```

Output:

```
<result>True<\/result>
```